# Is there any way to add delay to multiple audio outputs?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-jack, audio-sync

Lets say I have *speaker1* and *speaker2*, which both have different input delays.
In Windows there is a program, called [Voicemeeter](https://voicemeeter.com/), where you can output the system sound to *speaker1* and *speaker2* through multiple aux outputs and even add delay to each individual output, fixing the delay issue.

In Linux, with a program called [Jack](https://jackaudio.org/), the output routing would work, but I couldn't find any way to add delay to the speakers.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Being ineligible yet, unfortunately, I can't upvote this question, which is hard to believe that was almost not been asked (?!). But it's absolutely relevant!

Finally I've answered a similar question to myself. Mine is how to add a delay to the sound played from a single stream. The following recipe can be scaled to multiple streams though.

Here are the steps, inspired by the examples from [PulseAudio under the hood - Example setups](https://gavv.github.io/articles/pulseaudio-under-the-hood/#example-setups):

1. Set up a pipe sink:

   ```
   pactl load-module module-pipe-sink file="output.pcm"
   ```
2. Start (prepare to) playing from it with a delay of your choice (like 10 secs below):

   ```
   pacat --latency-msec=10000 output.pcm
   ```
3. Make sure to set your input stream (your speaker's one) to be played back on the created pipe sink. Do that in `pavucontrol`'s *Playback* tab.

Note that steps 2 and 3 can be done in any order.